# Python split for exec

Tags: python, for-loop, exec

My Var is
text comes from mysqldb
there I have

```
text = 
     data = ("123")
     data = ("345")
```

I've forgotten to post the \n

```
text = 'data = ("123") data = ("345")'
texts = text.split("\n") 
for text in texts:
    exec text
```

I'll get  ERROR

```
File "<string>", line 1
data = ("123")
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If I only print it is ok

```
text = 'data = ("123") data = ("345")'
texts = text.split("\n") 
for text in texts:
    print text
```

I'll get:

```
data = ("123")
data = ("345")
```

EDIT beginning

Comment: Your alleged outputs and error messages don't match what happens in my Python interpreter.  As an example, here's the [output of the last code snippet](http://ideone.com/ukawj), which is different from what you claim it is.  Post the real code, and we might be able to help.

Comment: I don't get what you get. I get `data = ("123") data = ("345")` all on one line.

Comment: This still isn't the real code.  The newly added code snippet isn't Python code, and the old ones are still wrong.  Voting to close for now.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a control character or a tab in the whites-pace after the equals sign.